# Why is my 'Wait method' not failing the TestNG test case?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

I have purposely changed the element so it is incorrect, but my test doesn't fail in TestNG. Any ideas?

My Code:

```
public void waitAndClickElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        element.click();
    } catch (TimeoutException timeEx) {
        this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
    } catch (StaleElementReferenceException elementUpdated) {
        this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to wait and click on element, Exception: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

@Test(priority = 2)
public void clickOnDrivingExperiencePage() throws Exception {
    basePage.waitAndClickElement(homepageHeader.link_DrivingExperiences);
}
```

[image]

**New Code Changes:**

```
    public void waitAndClickElement(WebElement element) throws InterruptedException {
    try {
        this.wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(element)).click();
        System.out.println("Successfully clicked on the WebElement: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Unable to wait and click on WebElement, Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        Assert.assertFalse(true, "Unable to wait and click on the WebElement, using locator: " + "<" + element.toString() + ">");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why should it fail? You catch the Exceptions and handle them.... besides "it doesn't fail" is rather vague. Could you describe what you were expecting, and what the results are you get with your current code?

Comment: @n247s please see the attached image the test is not failing even when I know the webelement locator is incorrect

Comment: I can only see that the method took 0.04 seconds. But what were you expecting? what console output, what test result and what do you get instead? Besides, have you tried a debugger to see what is really happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Unable to wait and click on element, Exception: " + e.getMessage());
}
```

You are catching all exceptions, so the test won't fail.

Comment: please see the attached image the test is not failing even when I know the webelement locator is incorrect

Comment: it outputs the exception to console but on TestNG it shows as passing, if i then add Assert.fail then the test case fails

Comment: Where is the console output? Where do you add Assert.fail?

Comment: I was getting the following output when the exception was caught: '"Unable to wait and click on element, Exception:....' even though TestNG was not displaying as failed. I have made changes to the code listed in my original post, your thoughts?

Comment: Now, if you see "Unable to wait..." then `Assert.assertFalse(true)` is supposed to mark the test as failed.

Comment: Adding an Assert.fail to the final catch block resolved the issue:} catch (Exception e) {
    Assert.fail();}