# Issue with Exceptions and TestNG and Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, testng

For example the following code should catch the Exception:

1. The exception gets outputted to the console `window == correct`
2. The exception does not show as a fail on `testNg == wrong`

Any ideas why this is happening?

**My code:**

```
    public void scrollToElementByLocator() {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("wrong locator")).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception! - unable to scroll to element, Exception: " + e.toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: `The exception does not show as a fail on testNg == wrong`, in this case, does the exception shown in Console? Or is it about marking the test as Failed?

Comment: @Naveen the exception gets outputted to the console, just dosnt show marked as red on the TestNG eclipse console, thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my 'Wait method' not failing or catching exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42156532/why-is-my-wait-method-not-failing-or-catching-exception)

Comment: This is the ***4th*** time you ask this question. If you are not satisfied with the answer set a bounty, don't ask the same question repeatedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TestNG marks a test as Fail, if the code inside the test raises any Exception.
```

In your code, as you are handling the exception on your own by catching it, no exception will be raised to the caller, so, `TestNG` never knows that an exception in being raised in the code.

Remove `try-catch` block, so exception will be raised from the test, so `TestNG` can mark the test as `Fail`.

try the following code:

```
@Test
public void scrollToElementByLocator() {
        driver.findElement(By.id("wrong locator")).click();
}
```

Note: You must mark the method with `@Test` annotation, to tell `TestNG` that it is a test method.

---

If you want perform some actions if exception raised, then try the following code (throw the exception you captured using `throw` keyword):

```
@Test
public void scrollToElementByLocator() {
    try {
        driver.findElement(By.id("wrong locator")).click();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception! - unable to scroll to element, Exception: " + e.toString()); //prints the exception
     throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but if the test wasnt marked as an exception when the wrong locator was purposely used, wouldnt the System.out.println housed in the catch{} block not get printed?

Comment: if you use wrong locator (i.e., locator which does not match any web element), then `NoSuchElementException` will be raised which will be passed to `catch` block. so, system.println prints the message. The best approach is `Never use try and catch block` unless you want to escape from `known failures`.

Comment: I strongly suggest learning `exception handling` in `Java` which will clear all of your doubts. here is the official doc: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/. you can find a plenty of articles related to the same.